# Using adjective as adverb

Tags: word-usage, flat-adverbs

I've heard a line in a song contained "...I slept peaceful on your shoulder...". Is this correct from a native speaker point of view?
Is peaceful here an adverb without a -ly form, or does it relate more to object "I" (like "I was peaceful and I slept...")

My situation is using "loud" as adverb with "dispute" verb. Is it appropriate to say "They dispute too loud"?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It would read better as "I slept, peaceful, on your shoulder" where _peaceful_ is an adjective describing how "I" was at the time. Without the commas it should be _peacefully_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adjectives are used to modify a verb, they are called "flat adverbs." Do they modify the subject or the verb? That's a good question, and it probably depend on the actual sentence, and even for a given sentence, the perceptions of native English speakers may differ.

*"They talk too loud"* is absolutely fine.

I wouldn't object to *"They argue too loud"*, and Google finds a number of hits for *"argued too loud"*.

However, Google doesn't find any hits for *"disputed too loud,"* and it doesn't sound right to me. I think the reason is that when I hear the verbs "talk" and "argue", I tend to think of people speaking, but when the verb *"dispute"* evokes a much more abstract type of disagreement.